# Pass an argument to callback function

Tags: jquery, callback

I want to pass an argument directly to the function in JQuery.

I used

```
$(this).prev()
```

to access my previous argument. But I want to access to this previous argument anytime I want, without prev method. My current code is as below

```
$(".a").click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle(1000,function(){
    $(this).prev().css("background-color","green");

    });
});
```

Comment: is it 'argument' or 'element' ?

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve? Is there anything at all that isn't working, or at least badly designed?

Comment: No, everything's working. Just wanted a better design

Comment: @ Tino M Thomas : it's argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a closure to merge the event object and the element into a single argument list:

```
$(".a").click(function(eve){
    (function ( e, p ) {
        $(e.target).next().slideToggle(1000,function(){
            $(p).css("background-color","green");
        });
    })( eve, $(this).prev() );
});
```

You may opt not to deliver the event object at all:

```
$(".a").click(function(eve){
    (function ( n, p ) {
        $(n).slideToggle(1000,function(){
            $(p).css("background-color","green");
        });
    })( $(this).next(), $(this).prev() );
});
```

Of course, your actual callback function can be factored out of the event handler registration:

```
function myClickCallback ( n, p ) {
    $(n).slideToggle(1000,function(){
        $(p).css("background-color","green");
    });
}

//...

$(".a").click(function(eve){
    myClickCallback ( $(this).next(), $(this).prev() );
});
```

That probably makes more sense in the context of some triggering action that is supposed to have an effect elsewhere. Such a behaviour is by no means recommended practice - non-local effects of user interaction in fact violate UI design recommendations:

```
function myClickCallback ( n, p ) {
    $(n).slideToggle(1000,function(){
        $(p).css("background-color","green");
    });
}

//...

$(".a").click(function(eve){
    myClickCallback ( $(some_other_element).next(), $(some_other_element).prev() );
});
```

**Demo**

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/collapsar/5mrbvrvn/5/) contains a PoC of the idea with a simplified callback function.

Comment: I used a closure to merge the event object and the element into a single argument list as you said. But my previous argument (.a) didn't change. nothing happened to the background color !

Comment: Are you sure to have assigned a class `a` to some element(s)? If you want to reference all anchors (`a` tags), use `$("a")` (without the period) as selector.